# My C++ ActiveMQ client can send messages, but not receive messages

Tags: c++, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

I have the ActiveMQ-CPP 2.2.1 Visual Studio 2005 project compiling and running.  In the console window, it shows the messages are being sent, though they're not being received.  I can both send and receive messages with ActiveMQ-CPP 2.0.1, but not 2.2.1.  I'm new to ActiveMQ and don't even know where to begin troubleshooting.  Any thoughts/suggestions/good place to start would be a great help.

It if helps, I'm using the ActiveMQ 5.1.0 binary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend posting this to the [user forum](http://activemq.apache.org/discussion-forums.html) to get the ActiveMQ C++ developers to help. Maybe even [raise a JIRA with a test case](http://activemq.apache.org/support.html)