# How can I observe what's happening under the hood of ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm experiencing an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248182/my-c-activemq-client-can-send-messages-but-not-receive-messages) with ActiveMQ and would like to trace/view all ActiveMQ activity.  The only log file I can find is one associated with persistent data (if this is turned on).  Are there any other log files I view or generate to tell me what's happening under the hood of ActiveMQ and why my consumers aren't consuming messages?  Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

activemq has a jmx interface that you can connect to.

this gives us access to consumer counts messages queued dequeue and all sorts of data on memory usage etc.

http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html

Has all the details to get you started.

I find it excellent in finding out whats going on with activemq.

A quick firing up of jconsole and you will be well on your way to finding out what is going on.

Paul

Answer (score 2):

Agreed. Also you can add the [logging interceptor](http://activemq.apache.org/logging-interceptor.html) which helps.

Finally for browsing messages, moving them, creating/deleting queues and sending message I highly recommend the new web console for ActiveMQ, Camel and many other [plugins](http://hawt.io/plugins/index.html): [hawtio](http://hawt.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Try [HawtIO](http://hawt.io/). Assuming you are not using Active MQ 5.9 you can add this feature to your broker. It is a much better web console and a good JMX monitoring utility as well.

http://www.christianposta.com/blog/?p=315